# UrlEncode will not encode anything

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm relatively new to ASP.net so I may be making a schoolboy error, however I can't get Server.UrlEncode to work (I'm using vb.net in a web forms project).

I'm using this code on a button click event on the originating form

```
Dim url As String
url = "CustomerDetailsUD.aspx?ID=" & Server.UrlEncode(cuIDSelected)
Response.Redirect(url)
```

In this case cuIDSelected is "106"

The destination page url is http://localhost:xxxxx/CustomerDetailsUD?ID=106

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected encoded value?

Comment: UrlEncode turns spaces into things like %20, it's not going to change a number into something else. What are you really wanting to see here?

Comment: @mason Not sure I need to know this?  I have a variable of 106, which I want to pick up in my destination page load event (to get record from a db) - using UrlDecode.  I just don't want the user to be able to see the ID=106 in their url for security reasons.

Comment: @RonBeyer - ah OK, I misunderstood how urlencode works.  Anybody suggest a way to encrypt/decrypt the string?

Comment: Why not use session variables instead? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx Then you don't have to worry about encryption/decryption, the session state stays on the server.

Comment: @PipecockJackson The reason I asked for it was so that I could understand what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: @mason Yes I see why you asked now.  My mistake for not understanding the quite obvious difference between encode and encrypt.  Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks Ron, a much better solution. Every day is a school day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess: You're confusing encoding with encryption.

Server.UrlEncode does not encrypt, and since 106 is a valid set of characters, nothing get's changed, try adding an invalid url symbol to cuIDSelected, such as '&' to see what it does

Comment: Yes- exactly right.  Thanks.  Told you it was a schoolboy error!